# Как в Android сделать промотку (scrollTo) в ScrollView, дочерним элементом в котором является LinearLayout с несколькими WebView?

Tags: java, android, webview, прокрутка

Нюанс в том, что промотку мне надо сделать, например, к bottom конкретного WebView, но данные в WebView загружаются после создания разметки, а видимо из-за этого в ScrollView данные о размерах элементов лэйаута получаются некорректные/неактуальные, поэтому либо не скроллится вообще, либо скроллится на меньшую длину, чем есть у элемента с загруженным контентом. Подскажите, как правильно обработать scroll в такой ситуации, если это вообще возможно? Или, наверно, как обновить данные о состоянии дочерних элементов ScrollView? Хотя у меня промотка должна быть по кнопке, но для проверки пробовал после загрузки контента сразу скроллить как-то так:

```
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            mWebView.scrollTo(0, 2000);
        }
}
```

И результат нулевой. Может кто-нибудь подкинет хоть какое-то направление, куда копать, как эту проблему победить?
Сам `webview` проматывать не надо, весь контент там умещается в несколько строк, надо `ScrollView` промотать на высоту конкретного webview или до низа конкретного `webview`, то есть нормально чтобы заработало `scrollView.scrollTo(0, myWebView.getBottom())` или `scrollView.scrollTo(0, myWebView.getContentHeight())`

Comment: @VAndrJ, мысль здравая, попробую, а чем от обычного scrollTo отличается smoothScrollTo, не подскажете?

Comment: да то же самое, только не резко прыгает в нужное место, а относительно плавно прокручивает.

Comment: Если вам нужно прокрутить `ScrollView`, зачем же вы прокручиваете `WebView`?

Comment: @VAndrJ, спасибо за помощь, отложенная прокрутка работает!

Comment: @metalurgus, а и правда, к ночи что-то совсем мозги не работают, а пример видимо все-таки рабочий в целом, попробую и его применить тоже.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сделайте отложенную прокрутку, может что-то не успевает. Как пример:

```
scrollView.postDelayed(new Runnable() { 
    @Override 
    public void run() { 
        scrollView.smoothScrollTo(0, myWebView.getBottom()); 
    } 
}, 300);
```